# How to cache a rails image variant that is directly uploaded to S3 with Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, caching, rails-activestorage

I have rails app that is using this code to generate a resized variant image in the view:

```
<%= image_tag @user.profile_photo.variant(resize_to_fit: [256, 256]), class: "profile-photo" %>
```

The image is uploaded directly to S3 using Active Storage and the sample javascript from the [Active Storage rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads).

My problem is that the image reloads on each page load (and flickers). I use the profile photo in the main nav for a user dropdown so it's quite distracting.

How do I cache this? I tried using `@user.profile_photo.variant(resize_to_fit: [256, 256]).processed`, but the `processed` method did not fix the flicker either.

Surely this is an issue for many people. What is the correct way to do this? Do I need to call the variant in my controller and then cache it there and just use an instance variable in my view?

Comment: Commenting to say I have the same problem and am trying to figure it out. I _think_ it might be fixed by Rails 6.1 by using the new proxying feature and setting the AWS bucket to public: true? I'm not totally sure yet. (public: true only works if you've already set all your existing files to be public, so be aware of that)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After upgrading to Rails 6.1 it now appears to only happen if I visit a page I've yet to visit yet. If I go to a page I've previously visited the image is cached. This seems like it's the intended behavior and I'm guessing it's due to Turbolinks? Is there a better way to handle this with Turbolinks though? I'm trying to do the same exact implementation as Basecamp.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm on Rails 6.1.4. @LeeMcAlilly did you manage to fix the flickering issue?

Comment: @MaxRah I haven't had this issue after upgrading past Rails 6.1.x. I did switch to `resize_to_fill` instead of `resize_to_fit` but I don't see how that is related.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm also using `resize_to_fill` but still experiencing the flickering.